# How to use Javascript file as a resources file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a Javascript a key value object and use it as my Resources for localization
I have made this Jascsript code in a javascript file:

```
    var Values = {

    lbl_CustomerName:"Customer name: "

}
```

now need to use this object in my HTML file:

```
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="../content/JS/Resources/en-us/Resources.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Values.lbl_CustomerName
</body>
</html>
```

but it's parsed as a plane text!
 I need to call this Object and access the key to show it's value in my HTML file how to do this?

Comment: That's not how Javascript works. You either need a pre-processor on your server-side that handles localization or you'll need to run some JS that takes the localized strings and inserts them into the DOM.

Comment: `<script>` tags around the Javascript would be a start.

Comment: Look at one of the many templating libraries out there...

Comment: `<script>document.write(Values.lbl_CustomerName)</script>` - but definitely not the best way to go about doing it. Look into a templating library such as Handlebars: http://handlebarsjs.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, the Javascript file must return an object, so I can use it on my page as follows:
**javascript:**

```
function resourcesObject() {
    return {
        "customerName": "Customer name";
    };
}
```

**HTML**

```
<script>
var resources=resourcesObject();
var customerName=resources["customerName"];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to parse a JavaScript code, you should wrap it inside a script tag.

```
<title>Title</title>
    <script src="../content/JS/Resources/en-us/Resources.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script> document.write(Values.lbl_CustomerName); </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Browsers have interpreters and virtual machines. Natively, they parse the codes as HTML. if you need to use other syntaxes like CSS and JavaScript, you should tell them hey browser, parse this section as a CSS, JavaScript.

That's why we need  and  tags

Comment: and there's no any work around to prevent writing the script tag ?

Comment: no, you can use javascript only inside `<script>` tag

Answer (score 0):

we can truly advice you to use a javascript framework like angular js that embed this kind of behavior inside the framework.

without javascript framework, you will need to modify the DOM by yourself to insert your expected value. If you want to do it in pure javascript function you can write a functio like :

```
function insertKey(elem,id) {
  elem.innerHTML = Values[id];
}
```

In your case it will look like that :

```
<title>Title</title>
    <script src="../content/JS/Resources/en-us/Resources.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function insertKey(elem,id) {
         elem.innerHTML = Values[id];
       }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div onload="insertKey(this,'lbl_CustomerName')"></div>
</body>
</html>
```